# How to split a linked-list into two lists

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

I'm writing a code to split a circular linked-list to two linked lists with equal number of codes, following is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node *ptr;
struct node {
    int element;
    ptr prev;
    ptr next;
};
typedef ptr list;
typedef ptr position;

int main() {
    list L=malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    list first=malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    list second=malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    splitlist(L,first,second);
    return 0;
}

void splitlist(list L, list first,list second) {
    position p,temp;
    p=malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp=malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    p=L;
    int count=0;

    while ((p)->next != L) {
        count++;
    }

    int c=count;
    while (c!=(count/2)-1) {
        p=(p)->next;
       temp=(p)->next;
    }

    first=L;
    (p)->next=NULL;
    second=temp;

    c=count;
    while (c!=(count/2)-1) {
       temp=(temp)->next;
    }
    (temp)->next=NULL;
}
```

When compiling my code it gives no errors but I'm not sure if it's working properly.

Comment: If the number of nodes is odd, you will not yield 2 equally sized lists as a result. Obviously.

Comment: 0) `list L=malloc(sizeof(struct node));` don't make circular linked-list.

Comment: Your while loops will not terminate as you never modify the "loop variable". If you know the number of iterations, you should prefer for-loops to make code more readable.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Ah I should have a temp that moves until I reach the last node of the list and assign its next as L . Right?

Comment: `but I'm not sure if it's working properly`. How about writing a few test cases, seeing where it fails, and posting a more pin pointed question
?

Comment: @user2225104 the program is for some unknown number of nodes

Comment: ... Or getting used to debug new code as early as possible. As for unknown number of nodes - you count the nodes, so you know. ``for(int c = 0; c < (count/2); c++ ) ...``

Comment: @RayaRateb maybe, Nothing is composed , only the area is secured.

Comment: You can do without counting and use a while loop if you simply iterate the source list and append the nodes to both target lists  in an alternating manner.

Comment: `while (c!=(count/2)-1)
{
   temp=(temp)->next;
}` : neither `c` nor `count` are changed in the while loop. Infinite loop on the way... Could you add `c--;` ?

Comment: And `second=temp;...temp=(temp)->next;` : the value of `second` is not changed twice. `second=temp` must be performed after the while loop.

Comment: @francis thanks for notifying me, I couldn't understand why everyone is telling me it's an infinite loop. I thought it's already written.

Comment: @francis I split the first list and let second point to the first node after the last node of L1, and then change temp to reach the last node in the second list. I don't want to change second

Comment: Right...Sorry ! If you wish to retrieve `first` and `second` out of the function, passing by pointer is required, even if `list` is already a pointer to a node. The prototype of the function must be `void splitlist(list L, list* first,list* second)` and in the function `*first=L;` and `*second=temp;`. In main : `list first,second;
splitlist(L,&first,&second);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get more readable and maintainable code, the first step to improve the code could be to create functions which help manipulating lists. Candidate functions are:

- ListInitialize()
- ListPushFront()
- ListPushBack()
- ListPopFront()
- ListPopBack()
- ListGetFirstNode()
- ListGetNextNode()
- ListGetFront()
- ListGetBack()
- ListEmpty()
- ...

With a proper set of arguments and return values of course.
Then you can write your splitlist function using those basic list operation functions and your code will be easier to read and to reason about.

Also, in order to handle an empty list, you should have an extra list type which is not just a pointer to a node.

```
typedef struct Node_tag { int value; struct Node_tag *next; struct Node_tag *prev } Node, *NodePtr;
typedef struct IntList_tag { NodePtr front; NodePtr back; } IntList;

// Creates an empty list.
void ListInitialize( IntList *pList ) { pList->front = NULL; pList->back = NULL; }
void ListPushFront( IntList *pList, int value ) 
{ NodePtr newNode = malloc(sizeof(Node)); 
  if(NULL != newNode ) 
  { newNode->next = pList->front; 
    newNode->prev = NULL; newNode->value = value; 
    pList->front = newNode; 
    if( pList->back == NULL ) pList->back = newNode; // first element...
  }
}
// ...
```

Eventually, using those functions, you can write `splitlist()` function in a concise and noise-free way:

```
void splitlist( IntList * source, IntList *target1, IntList *target2 )
{
     IntList * currentTarget = target1;
     for( NodePtr currentNode = ListGetFirstNode(source); currentNode != NULL; currentNode = ListGetNextNode(currentNode) )
     {
          ListPushBack(currentTarget, currentNode->value );
          if(currentTarget == target1 ) currentTarget = target2; 
          else currentTarget = target1;
     }
}
```

It might appear that it is much work to create all those other list functions if all you want is splitlist. But in real world applications you will most likely want all those other functions as well (or you have them already). Only in homework situations, this looks a bit funny.

Answer (score 0):

Example code. Using typedef for node to be compatible with Microsoft C compilers (C89). Note sometimes the pointer to a circular list is a pointer to the last node of the circular list, (which contains a pointer to the first node of the circular list), allowing for faster appends. This example assumes list pointers are pointers to first nodes, but could be modified to assume list pointers are to last nodes.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct _node{
struct _node *next;
int data;
}node;

node * splitlist(node * psrc, node ** ppdst1, node ** ppdst2)
{
node *ps = psrc;
node ** ppd1 = ppdst1;
node ** ppd2 = ppdst2;
    *ppd1 = *ppd2 = NULL;
    if(ps == NULL)
        return NULL;
    while(1){
        *ppd1 = ps;
        ps = *(ppd1 = &(ps->next));
        if(ps == psrc)
            break;
        *ppd2 = ps;
        ps = *(ppd2 = &(ps->next));
        if(ps == psrc)
            break;
    }
    *ppd1 = *ppdst1;
    *ppd2 = *ppdst2;
    return NULL;
}

main()
{
node a[8] = {{&a[1],0},{&a[2],1},{&a[3],2},{&a[4],3},
             {&a[5],4},{&a[6],5},{&a[7],6},{&a[0],7}};
node *pa = &a[0];
node *pb = NULL;
node *pc = NULL;
    pa = splitlist(pa, &pb, &pc);
    return 0;
}
```